# Helping out our sister site, Expats (Progress: 100%!!) - thanks to all who helped on the goal

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, expat-questions

[Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered) is doing well in visits, users, but lacking in answer rate.

As such, like we've done on travel in the past with success, I've created a [challenge on meta.expats](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/2017-trending-our-answered-percentage-ranking-to-1st).

[Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered) shares so many users with Travel, as the topics covered are similar but different.  As a result, helping [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/unanswered) helps us - if they have good answers that appear first in search results, we'll get fewer off topic questions (hooray!).

To that end, if you have 2-10 minutes, can you please hop on over to the link and see if you can do anything to help. Who knows, you might even get a badge or two ;)

**Progress in title reflects the progress from 76% answered to the goal of 90% answered.**

Comment: I always answer questions for Czech Republic where I live. Unfortunately I don't know much about long term visas in other countries :/

Comment: @JonathanReez well you can still help with close votes on unclear / off-topic questions ;)

Comment: Maybe a direct link to [expats.se] would make this post trigger more visits :) Going there through the challenge in Meta takes a couple clicks more to get there!

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, edited in some links :)

Comment: That's a cool and fast mod! Now it is a kind of _Minesweeper_ where it is impossible not to click at the link at least once :)

Comment: @fedorqui click bait! Click bait! :)

Comment: Is it possible for a link to go directly to a list of unanswered questions?

Comment: I scrolled through a lot of questions before I found one I could answer.  It already had a correct answer in comments, so I procrastinated.  I hesitate to names names, but if you thing you might have done that, please go look.

Comment: @WGroleau, you can move the information from the comments to an answer yourself. No need to put that off. Just mention what you are doing in your post. It's of great help.

Comment: I know that.  I wanted to give the writer(s) a chance to do it.  And then I got on a Greyhound bus, where they usually have free WiFi but rarely internet and never SSL.

Comment: @WGroleau I've changed all the expats links above to go directly to the unanswered questions. No excuses now ;) (Although I just got off a 3.5 hour Greyhound bus and feel your pain re the wifi)

Comment: I saw some questions marked as Duplicate. Isnt there some one clearing that queue.https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9978/what-visa-do-i-need-to-complete-an-unpaid-internship-in-new-york

Comment: This post is a great example of how this site has really helped. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/how-to-help-my-mother-in-law-migrate-no-lawyer-wanted It helped secure the visa for the Mother all based on the responses from our site. Good work there

Comment: @pal4life can't cross-duplicate from expats to travel, unfortunately

Comment: hmm...now let's lock this question

Comment: and oh let's keep up the good work otherwise it will fall behind 90% again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped - we got the answer rate up to 90%, and answered a good many number of questions in the time, as well as closing off some unclear/duplicates in the process.

Obviously though, 90% is not 100%, and we'd love any help over on expats, even adding new, useful answers to previously answered questions.

Thanks!